# Axios request in NextJS App with Strapi API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I have a problem with my NextJS App. I want to create a Portfolio on my website, using Strapi to add some content when I realize new projects. I can't succeed to extract the data array from Axios tu use it in my App. It is blocked in my GetProjects function.

This is the Page.jsx

```
import styles from './page.module.css'
import Introduce from './components/Introduce'
import Process from './components/Process'
import Scaling from './components/Scaling'
import Techs from './components/Techs'
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio'
import Socials from './components/Socials'
import variables from './globals.scss'
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <main className='container-fluid'>
      <Introduce />
      <Process />
      <Scaling />
      <Techs />
      <Portfolio />
      <Socials />      
    </main>
  )
}
```

The portfolio component :

```
import React from "react";
import GetProjects from "./GetProjects.jsx";

function Portfolio() {


    return (

        <div className='vh-100 d-flex align-items-center slide bg-waterblue row justify-content-center'>
            <div className='col-md-5'>
                <h2 className="text-lg-start text-center fw-bold title text-gold">My Portfolio.</h2>
                <p className="text-light text-lg-start text-center fw-semibold">Some images illustrate better
                    than long speaches.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
                <div className="row row-cols-4">
                    <div className="row">
                    <GetProjects />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Portfolio;
```

And this is the GetProjects.jsx component, including the function that doesn't work:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function GetProjects() {

    async function getData() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/projects?populate=*');
            const data = response.data.data;
            // console.log(data);

            return (
                <div>
                    {function renderData(data) {
                        data.map(project => {
                            <li>{project.attributes.title}</li>
                        })
                        
                        
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    {renderData(data)/* Doesn't works */}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        
                    }}

                </div>
            )

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error); // Don't forget to add "?populate=*" to the API endpoint.
        }
    }

    getData()

}

export default GetProjects;
```

Do you have advice? Some idea to extract that array and use it in the app?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Sam! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :) –

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return` in `GetProjects` to have something displayed on the page. As you did, it will return `undifined`. Also, you could simplify your code to:

```
import axios from "axios";

async function getData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/projects?populate=*");
    const data = response.data.data;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return [];
  }
}

async function GetProjects() {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((project, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{project.attributes.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default GetProjects;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things you need to move the async function to get data into a React.useEffect hook and pass the result back into some react state. Then use that state to render the list.

You can read more about this in the docs: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

async function getData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/projects?populate=*');
    const data = response.data.data;
    // console.log(data);

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // Don't forget to add "?populate=*" to the API endpoint.
  }
}

function GetProjects() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const runner = async () => {
      const newData = await getData();
      setData(newData);
    };
    runner();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.map((project) => (
          <li key={project?.attributes?.title}>{project?.attributes?.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GetProjects;
```